# Pandas: asfreq strange behavior with timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm trying to convert monthly timeseries to annual scale without changing values.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(url_inflation, delimiter='\t')
df.head()

    date    value
0   2019-09 -0.0016
1   2019-08 -0.0024
2   2019-07 0.0020
3   2019-06 0.0004
4   2019-05 0.0034
```

Then I convert the date column to datetime format and set it as index:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, yearfirst=True, format='%Y-%m')

df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

It looks like the index is correct:

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 345 entries, 2019-09-01 to 1991-01-01
Data columns (total 1 columns):
value    345 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 5.4 KB
```

And when I use asfreq it outputs an empty DataFrame with DatetimeIndex:

```
df.asfreq(freq='A')

date    value

df.asfreq(freq='A').info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 0 entries
Freq: A
Data columns (total 2 columns):
date     0 non-null object
value    0 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 0.0+ bytes
```

It seems to be working when groupby is used:

```
df1=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(level='date', freq='A')).nth(11)
df1.tail()

date        value
2014-12-31  0.0262
2015-12-31  0.0077
2016-12-31  0.0040
2017-12-31  0.0042
2018-12-31  0.0084
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I want to use the original monthly values. First month value for instance (last month would do also). Resample is working with this data but it applies some kind of function such as mean() or sum(). I just want to "filter" the data ...

Comment: Could you be more specific on "I just want to "filter" the data". Could you show an example of what you are trying to do?
Excuse my ignorance, what (freq='A') supposes to do?

Comment: @powerPixie you can consider the output of **groupby** as an example of correct result. That's what I wanted to get. However I can't understand why .asfreq is not showing the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to sort index first before using the `asfreq()`.

Try:

```
df = df.sort_index().asfreq(freq='A')
```

Or: use `resample()`

```
df = df.resample('A').asfreq()
```

use `freq='AS'` for start of the year.

**EDIT1:**

You can also use an `.agg()` to `.resample()` to get your expected result.

```
df = df.resample('AS').agg('sum')
```

Output:

```
             value
date              
2017-01-01  3.0018
2018-01-01  2.0018
2019-01-01  1.0018
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However after sorting all the data has NaN values ...

Comment: df.resample('A').asfreq() gives also NaN in values

Comment: `freq='A'` will use the last day of the year and `freq='AS'` will use the first day of the year. If you have data for 1st day of the year or last day of the year in your df, then it will be returned as per the `freq` value. What do you have in your `df['date']` column after `df.set_index`?

Comment: See EDIT1 - hope it helps

Comment: Thanks alot! That was freq='AS'  isntead 'A' as the original data had values for the first dates of the months.

Comment: Glad, I was able to help.